# How to select the cell underneath and return a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Essentially I have a list of subscriptions, I need to scan through the month values to find anything that is over a month, then copy it to the other sheet and take a month off, as well as a months worth of money.

The main part that I am struggling with is, after copying and editing, then moving down to the next cell, I figured I could do this with a loop, adding one to the cell count every time.

This doesn't seem to work, this is the line I am having issues with.

`spreadsheet.setActiveRange('C' + +cellCount);`

This is the full function so far.

```
  //define spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var count = -1;
  var cellCount = 3;

  //spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bot Purchase History (February)', true);
  //spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Bot Purchase History (March)', true)

  while (count < 0) {
    // select the first cell C3
    spreadsheet.setActiveRange('C' + +cellCount);
    var cell = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
    Logger.log(cell);
    if(cellCount > 20){
      count = 1
    }
  }
};
```

Here is an image of the sheets, compiled into one.

Edit: Apologies for not being clear, I'm trying to print the value of C3, then the value of C4 then C5, C6 C7 At the moment the code isn't getting past spreadsheet.setActiveRange('C' + +cellCount);

This will be the beginning of a much larger section of code. I do not want to simply print C3:C100, I need to print each cell individually to proceed.

For ease of access, I have put both 'sheets' onto one

[image]

Comment: In your code cellCount always remains at 3

Comment: Perhaps you want this `var cellCount = spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValue();` I don't knoow because it's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, I'm trying to print the value of C3, then the value of C4 then C5, C6 C7

At the moment the code isn't getting past 

```spreadsheet.setActiveRange('C' + +cellCount);```

Comment: setActiveRange() requires a range object not a string

Comment: Okay, perfect, how do I construct a range object from a string and an integer, or is it not that simple :S

Comment: [sheet.getRange() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var counter = 3; counter <= 8; counter = counter + 1) { 
  spreadsheet.setActiveRange(spreadsheet.getRange('C' + counter));
  Logger.log(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getValue());
}
```